# Spark SQL Row_number() PartitionBy Sort Desc

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I've successfully create a `row_number()` `partitionBy` by in Spark using Window, but would like to sort this by descending, instead of the default ascending.  Here is my working code:

```
from pyspark import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row, functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

data_cooccur.select("driver", "also_item", "unit_count", 
    F.rowNumber().over(Window.partitionBy("driver").orderBy("unit_count")).alias("rowNum")).show()
```

That gives me this result:

```
 +------+---------+----------+------+
 |driver|also_item|unit_count|rowNum|
 +------+---------+----------+------+
 |   s10|      s11|         1|     1|
 |   s10|      s13|         1|     2|
 |   s10|      s17|         1|     3|
```

And here I add the desc() to order descending:

```
data_cooccur.select("driver", "also_item", "unit_count", F.rowNumber().over(Window.partitionBy("driver").orderBy("unit_count").desc()).alias("rowNum")).show()
```

And get this error:

> AttributeError: 'WindowSpec' object has no attribute 'desc'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: On my PySpark (2.2.0) I have to use `row_number` instead of `rowNumber`.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

`desc` should be applied on a column not a window definition. You can use either a method on a column:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

F.row_number().over(
    Window.partitionBy("driver").orderBy(col("unit_count").desc())
)
```

or a standalone function:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

F.row_number().over(
    Window.partitionBy("driver").orderBy(desc("unit_count"))
)
```

Comment: strange the pyspark `orderBy` is different from the `window.orderBy` as one accepts an ascending and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use the SQL code in Spark-SQL:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .master('local[*]')\
    .appName('Test')\
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sql("""
    select driver
        ,also_item
        ,unit_count
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY driver ORDER BY unit_count DESC) AS rowNum
    from data_cooccur
""").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
df.orderBy(desc("col"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Actually, I tried looking more into this, and it appears to not work. (in fact it throws an error). The reason why it didn't work is that I had this code under a call to `display()` in Databricks (code after the `display()` call is never run). It seems like the `orderBy()` on a dataframe and the `orderBy()` on a `window` are not actually the same. I will keep this answer up just for negative confirmation

<s>As of PySpark 2.4,(and probably earlier), simply adding in the keyword `ascending=False` into the `orderBy` call works for me.</s>

Ex.

`personal_recos.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("COLLECTOR_NUMBER").orderBy("count", ascending=False)))`

and

`personal_recos.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("COLLECTOR_NUMBER").orderBy(F.col("count").desc())))`

seem to give me the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

my_new_df = df.select(df["STREET NAME"]).distinct()

# Count the rows in my_new_df 
print("\nThere are %d rows in the my_new_df DataFrame.\n" % my_new_df .count())

# Add a ROW_ID
my_new_df = my_new_df .withColumn('ROW_ID', F.monotonically_increasing_id())

# Show the rows with 10 highest IDs in the set and sort DESC
my_new_df .orderBy(my_new_df .ROW_ID.desc()).show(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, similar to @zero333's `col` option is using sorting on the column.

```
data_cooccur.select("driver", "also_item", "unit_count", F.rowNumber().over(Window.partitionBy("driver").orderBy(data_cooccur["unit_count"].desc())).alias("rowNum")).show()
```